# After adding admob application crashes

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

After compiling the apk file and launching the application on the phone. The application gives an error. All this happens after adding the admob plugin

```
Admob Android Manifest:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.google.unity.ads" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <application>
    <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-hidden" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>

    Log error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.TestCom.Test, PID: 21176
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

Comment: What is your plugin version?

Comment: Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v5.1.0

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.google.unity.ads" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1"> <application> <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" /> <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-hidden" /> </application> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> </manifest>

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the bad explanation of the problem.
I did it : 'Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve' and it helped